# What does this tcpdump line means?

Tags: man, tcpdump, filter

Reading the manpage of `tcpdump` I found this example

```
tcpdump 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-fin) != 0 and not src and dst net localnet'
```

but I don't understand it, especially the last part.

The `tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-fin) != 0` part filters all the packets having either the SYN or the FIN bit set.

What does `not src and dst net localnet` filter?

The explanation in the same manpage says

> To print the start and end packets (the SYN and FIN  packets)  of  each
>          TCP conversation that involves a non-local host.

but in my opinion `src` is not an expression by itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse the second part of that filter thusly

```
not ( (src and dest) net localnet )
```

It's shorthand for

```
not src net localnet and not dest net localnet
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that in order to use logical operator (as `and`) I MUST HAVE a complete true or false expression in every side.
If I write `not(src net localnet and dst net localnet)`, does it have the same meaning?